Recognize and process quotation mark (")
I'm trying to change every (") quotation mark in A1 to (-) then print the result in B1.
Sub ReplaceQuotes()
    Dim inputText As String
    Dim outputText As String
    
    inputText = Range("A1").Value
    
    outputText = Replace(inputText, """", "-")
    
    Range("B1").Value = outputText
End Sub

Example Text:

A popular proverb says, “A society grows great when old men plant
trees under whose shade they will never sit.” When we dispose of
radioactive waste, we don’t say, “Who cares if this poisons people
centuries from now?” Similarly, few of us who care about climate
change or pollution do so solely for the sake of people alive today.

The result was the same. Nothing changed.
Tried Chr(43) instead of """".
Other characters like "A" work.

Would help to provide a sample of the type of text you're dealing with.  Possibly the "quotes" in your text are not Chr(34) but some other character(s) ?

This works for me. Maybe there is something with processedTextC

Maybe my explanation was not enough. So changed the question a little bit.

Not sure if this is the full issue but the sample quote is not using straight quotes chr(34) it is using chr(147) and chr(148)

Chr(147) and Chr(148) didn't work, either. :'(

Loop through each character of the string and see what the character and its ascii value are. It works as intended for me in the given example.

This may not make sense but excel is not recognizing the double quotes in your the sentence as actual double quotes. Most times when you copy things from other sources and paste them, excel doesnt see them as those traditional characters they are called non-printing characters. So i just copied one of the quotes in the sentence and put it directly in the VBA.
Sub ReplaceQuotes()
    Dim inputText As String
    Dim outputText As String

    inputText = Range("A1").Value

    outputText = Replace(inputText, "“", "-")

    Range("B1").Value = outputText

End Sub

You will notice the difference in the code i put up. The quotes and the one in the sentence are not the same.

ChrW(8221) solved the problem. But thanks for your explanation.

It is not Excel's fault that it does not recognize " (U+0022) as “ (U+201C), it is because they are different characters. There are no "non-printing characters" at play either.
